# How to get the sum based on multiple conditions in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

Hi I'm a beginner in power BI and would like some help with a problem I have.

I need to have the sum of value for each combination of "order no", "line no", "rel no" ONLY for the highest value of "shipment no" and where "is last snapshot" = 1

So for example:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFMR7.png)
here I want to only sum the marked values

I tried the following:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwNJX.png)

But I wanted to only see the marked values and the sum should be 3000.

How can I do this in power BI? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a measure like this:

```
Value Measure = 
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[order no] , 
        'Table'[line no] ,
        'Table'[rel no] ,
        "value", 
        VAR _shipment = MAX ( 'Table'[shipment no] ) 
        RETURN CALCULATE ( 
            SUM ( 'Table'[value] ) , 
            'Table'[is last snapshot] = 1 ,
            'Table'[shipment no] = _shipment
        )
    )
RETURN
SUMX ( 
    _tbl , 
    [value]
)
```

It's not pretty, perhaps it can be done in a better way. Result in a table visual:

[image]

Comment: This worked and is good enough for me now, thanks a lot! :)